# Use Field History Reports For Daily Values When No Change Occurrs

Tags: reporting, field-history

I'm trying to use Field History reporting to provide daily, weekly, monthly counts of a field for a record which gets updated every day but the field in question may not get updated the whole time, therefore there may not be a Field History entry for the field every day.  Do you know how I can get around this? I want to basically have a report which shows the actual value every day and as it "may" get updated each time the record itself is updated I need to use History reporting for the changes, however History reporting will be missing days where no change occurs.
If I can fudge a value every day in the History report this would meet my needs.

Thanks in advance or any tips/suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce OOTB Field History works when there is a change in values.

Since it is implicit object, we cannot create any fields at this object. If you have that kind of specific requirement then you need to create custom object to store values on daily basis either it has been changed or not.

If you have custom object then reports can be built easily based on your requirement.

You should also think about the volume of data in that object and archival strategy for long run.

Comment: Hi Santanu, This is what I thought alright. Thanks.